# How do I go from a TIFF with symbology to polygons for each label?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

So I am trying to take this TIFF layer and convert it to polygons with their designated label[image]

[image]

For example I want a shapefile that has polygons for "-11.374 - 0", "0 - 6", "6 - 13", and "13 to 20". I know that I need to use the tool raster calculator and other Spatial Analyst tools but confused to where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following workflow:

- Use [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) tool to reclassify the range of values,"-11.374 -
  0", "0 - 6", "6 - 13", and "13 to 20", into 4 classes, something like
  this:

`-11.374 - 0 -> 0`

`0 - 6 -> 6`

`6 - 13 -> 13`

`13 to 20 -> 20`

- Then convert the output classified raster into polygon using [Raster
  to polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) tool.
- Add new field in the attribute table of the polygon shapefile with a text type and populate the new field with the original values before classification.

`0 -> -11.374 - 0`

`6 -> 0 - 6`

`13 -> 6 - 13`

`20 -> 13 to 20`